# Running a program from Java(triggered by cron)

Tags: java, process, cron

I have a cron job which launches a java program.
This java program launches some other program(example "youtube-dl").
The java program uses Process, Runtime, etc...(using code found on multiple web sites)
It also does a process.waitFor();
but the java program exists without wait.
The java program quits and with it is also killing the youtube-dl process(child process).

The same java program when run from command line(not from cron) runs fine(i am able to see youtube-dl as part of process list).
Having trouble pasting the code here (due to formatting)
pasted the code here http://pastebin.com/RUgubDZ9

here is the log...

    `Tue Mar 17 19:01:06 UTC 2015 : youtube-dl is not running.  launching now...
    Tue Mar 17 19:02:06 UTC 2015 : youtube-dl is not running.  launching     now...
    Tue Mar 17 19:04:58 UTC 2015 : youtube-dl is not running.  launching now...`

Comment: Do you run youtube-dl from a daemon thread?

Comment: you mean in a separate thread in Java?  No.  The java program exists before youtube-dl completes.  Not sure if it even starts...

Comment: Yes. If your external process is launched from a daemon thread, then the jvm will shutdown even if that thread is still blocked by `process.waitFor()`. Have you tried running youtube-dl from cron? Maybe it's some sort of permission problem - that would make things the other way around though (instantly exiting youtube-dl vs. jvm shutdown killing youtube-dl in the process).

Comment: I have a wget cron job script as well as a youtube cron job script...
Both the scripts are scheduled to run every minute.
Both run in their own directory and both have a file '0' which contain the wget and youtube-dl commands.

I can see that the wget script executes and launches the wget command( i can see it in ps aux).
The youtube cron scipt exeutes, but I do not see any youtube-dl in the ps aux output

Comment: my shell script is here http://pastebin.com/udVBCmVa

Comment: Seems like your `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("youtube-dl [...]")` is throwing an exception. Log the exception instead of doing `e.printStackTrace()` and post the result. Uneducated guess: `youtube-dl` is in your user's PATH, but not in the PATH of the user used by cron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cron script was not executing for youtube-dl (but was working fine for an identical script involving wget).
The reason may be because wget was already available in raspbian where was youtube-dl was manually installed by me.

Even though wget as well as youtube-dl works fine in any script launched by the user, the youtube-dl script failed when triggered by cron.

I changed how youtube-dl is called.
Earlier it was 
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhIfQ-IhhPM

now it is modified to 
python /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhIfQ-IhhPM

This works from cron perfectly.

Now, there is no need for me to launch the whole thing from Java.  Shell script will do...